# Windows Forms | MenuStrip Sub-Items (ToolStripMenuItem) changing Cursor won't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, menustrip

I want to have a Hand Cursor for all ToolStripMenuItems.

So i change it in the MouseEnter and MouseLeave Events with `this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;` & `this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;`. I've disabled latter for debugging purpose, so i can see if it changes at all.

It only works for "Root" Items. Not for their Sub-ToolStripMenuItems.
The Events fire, it's just like the Cursor get's overridden by Sub-Items.

Any help would be appreciated, it looks weird with the default Cursor.
I am using the latest version of VS 2019 and work with .NET Framework 4.8

Here is a little screen:

[image: Problem Description as Screen]

System-Info:

- Edition:  Windows 10 Pro
- Version:  20H2
- OS-Build: 19042.746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me, both for root and sub items:

```
    private void ...ToolStripMenuItem_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

    private void ..ToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: Oh thats great, thanks. I really suffered from this simple issue. Did not tested Move Event instead for hours ^^